# ignore a directory for recent items in Windows 7/8/10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10, jumplist

Is there a way to tell Windows 7/8/10 to completely ignore a folder when tracking it's recent items?  Not just a single program, but anything making use of files in a given directory.  Jumplists don't seem to cover this.

I have to believe there's a mechanism for this, as lots of temporary files and such don't get recorded in the recent items list.

So where is the OS keeping track of what not to include in the recent items list?  Is it an NTFS attribute?  Or is there a policy involved?

**I specifically DO NOT want to disable recent item tracking entirely.**  It's a useful feature, most of the time.  But for certain directories I'd prefer to avoid the recent list getting filled up with listings from some directories.

Comment: Not that I have ever found. Also there is file history stored in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this a bit and wrote a powershell script to edit the recent items.  This only handles shortcut links (*.lnk files).  It doesn't handle search results or other things that could possibly end up in the recent items.  But for my purposes it's good enough.

```
# cleanRecent.ps1
# 
# Searches through the target path names of files in the 'Recent Items' special folder
# if the path name contains the matchText string then it deletes the link (NOT THE TARGET FILE)
#
# Handy to keep clutter or problematic folders out of the recent folder list
#
# To make it happen automagically set up a Task Scheduler job to trigger on user logon situations.  
#

#
# adding ability to purge Run menu items also
# stored in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU
#

# TO USE: edit the contents of the matchArray to whatever you're trying to remove

$matchArray = "somefolder","someotherfolder"

$recentFolder = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Recent")

# create a COM shell to handle shortcut links
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

ForEach ($recentFile in Get-Childitem -recurse $recentFolder -Include *.lnk) {

        $recentObject = $Shell.CreateShortcut($recentFile)
        $recentPath = $recentObject.TargetPath

        ForEach ($matchArrayText in $matchArray) {
            if ($recentPath.Contains($matchArrayText)) {
                write-output $recentObject.FullName
                Remove-Item -LiteralPath $recentObject.FullName -force
            }
        }
}
```